# I am trying to write a function xyz(a) that loops through the no.s 0 through a and returns "Jackpot" if it finds the number 777 .or else "Try again

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax-error

```
def xyz(a):
 i=0
 while i>=a:
   if i==777:
      return"Jackpot"
   else:
      return"Try again"
      i+=1
```

The above when i am running gives me no output. unable to figure out what's missing

Comment: How do you call the function? It doesn't print anything itself.

Comment: You are returning before incrementing

Comment: def xyz(a):
    i=0
    while i>=a:
      if i==777:
        return "Jackpot"
    else:
        return "Try again"
        i+=1

Comment: You function do like this: if i equal to 777 then return "jackpot" otherwise return "Try again" and finish program.

Comment: Yes , thats the objective .but then in the above case it should return Try again as out put

Comment: This function essentially should check whether `a` is greater or equals to `777`, why do you even need a loop?

Comment: @user2201502 the whole program logic is wrong!

Comment: Why do you even need a loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors!

1. If you return before increment, you'll never have an increment.
2. If you return after increment , no point of `while` loop.

**Solution**

> Simple `if else`

```
def xyz(a):


   if a==777:
      return "Jackpot"
   else:
      # i+=1
      # return "Try again"
      return ("Try Again")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any information about what exactly you are trying to do all I can do is give you some advise based on what I can infer from your code. Notice that you are returning a value meaning you stop the execution of the while loop at the first iteration always (if you are 100% certain about the implementation of the function and your desired output is 'try again' then you have to 'catch' the returned value of the function and print that). Also check the while condition. I is initialised at 0 so (for me at least) it would make sense to check if i is less than a (but again this comes from my intuition about the code).